# How to enable wso2am 4.1 api.log for all the APIs instead of enabling per API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

wso2 api manager version 4.1 has a feature to enable logs for requests and responses going through the WSO2 API Gateway.
ref: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/api-manager/monitoring-api-logs/

I'm looking for an option to enable it for all APIs by default. I only required BASIC logs.

Requirement is to have all the requests and responses written in to the api.log by default.
These logs will be used for generate metrics as well as display log entries in a grafana/kibana dashboards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a method you can do this with a single command. But you can use a script like the following to do this.

```bash
apictl login dev -u admin -p admin

for j in $(apictl get apis -e dev --format "{{ .Id }}")    
do
    echo "Setting log level for API: $j"
    apictl set api-logging --api-id "$j" --log-level full --environment dev --verbose
done
```

Above is a reference script. Build on top of it as needed.

On a different note, if you are looking for API metrics you should be able to get them from OOB analytics features. You can even extend the default implementation and tailer to suit your need. Take a look at [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/) document.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling loging for requests/ responses for all the APIs will have a performnace impact. We do have a way of visualizing API analytics in Kibana out-of-the-box using API Manager ELK extensions. Bets to follow - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/

Comment: Thank you @joy. I'm planning to enable analytics as per this guide and use the apim_metrics.log content to expose the metrics I want using grok exporter to Prometheus.